# Use all files ending in .ann in one directory as y1 and y2 values for Cohen's Kappa

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two directories: 'ann-1' and 'ann-2', in these directories I have text files and .ann files. Is there a way I can use all .ann files from the first directory as the y1 value and all .ann files from the second directory as the y2 value?

```
sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score(y1, y2, *, labels=None, weights=None, sample_weight=None)
```

I'm really not sure if I even interpreted scikit's documentation correctly, as their documentation is not very detailed.

Comment: What is stored inside the `.ann` files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more details regarding the `.ann` files, please show us what's inside them. I'll update the answer if you add more details.

Now, in order to calculate the Cohen's Kappa coefficient, you need to pass two array-like structures of the same length to the function. The first array must be the observed values of the independent variable and the second array must contain the predicted labels. Here's a similar example to the one in the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#cohen-kappa):

```py
# Import function
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score

# y1 and y2 as lists
y_true = [0, 0, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1]

# Calculate coefficient
k = cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

In order to store the `.ann` files from `ann-1` in `y1` and the `.ann` files from `ann-2` in `y2`, you can try something along these lines (you did not show the structure of the directories or the content of the files, so it may or may not work, but you can adapt the code to your needs):

```py
# Import file browser library
import os

# Declare paths to each directory
path_1 = './path_to_ann-1/'
path_2 = './path_to_ann-2/'

# Lists of files in each folder
ann_1 = os.listdir(path_1)
ann_2 = os.listdir(path_2)

# For loop to read files and calculate metric
for file_1, file_2 in zip(ann_1, ann_2):
    # Check if they're .ann or .txt files
    if file_1[-4:] == '.ann' and file_2[-4:] == '.ann':
        # Change separator and columns as you see fit
        y1 = pd.read_csv(path_1 + file_1, sep='|')['target'].values
        y2 = pd.read_csv(path_2 + file_2, sep='|')['perdiction'].values
        # Calculate metric
        m = cohen_kappa_score(y1, y2)
        # Print metric
        print(file_1, 'and', file_2, 'yield', m)
```